# to make two bucle frame in complete screen

Tags: java, android

i want to make a dog in complete screen, and i have two images. Only i want a dog saying no with fingers.

case STATE_AFTER_CHEAT:

```
            notocarEscalado = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(notocarEscalado, screenWidth, screenHeight, true);
            notocar2Escalado = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(notocar2Escalado, screenWidth, screenHeight, true);



            canvas.drawBitmap(notocar2Escalado, 0, 0, null);



            canvas.drawBitmap(notocarEscalado, 0, 0, null);


            canvas.drawBitmap(notocar2Escalado, 0, 0, null);

            canvas.drawBitmap(notocarEscalado, 0, 0, null);

            //canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                drawCenteredText(canvas, "Head start!", "", getContext().getString(R.string.TocarParaContinuar));
                break;
```